# How to restrict read access/visibility of a repository?

Tags: azure-devops

In the azure doc it is recommended to use as few projects as possible in one organization.
Now I have the scenario that I need to restrict read access to certain Git repositories.

How would I accomplish that?
From what I have seen in the documentation and devops itself I have the feeling that I have to create a dedicated project and restrict the access to the project to which those repositories belong to.

If I now see the URL of a Git repo I cannot even see the project name at all. Does that mean that GIT repositories belong more to an organization than to a project?

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git repo belongs only to a project. To restrict access you can:

1. Create new security group: [Project-level groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#project-level-groups)
2. Add it into Git repo groups and deny Read access. [Set Git repository permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions)

[image]